# Create observable from array

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I want to subscribe to a list of events based on their ids. I am using **AngularFire2** and **Firebase**. Not sure if creating an observable while subscribing to another is right.

```
eventsRef: AngularFireList<any>
events: Observable<any[]>
o2: Observable<any[]>


//get all event ids for a particular user
this.eventsRef = db.list(`eventsGuestsLookup/${this.id}`)
this.events = this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => (c.payload.key))
    )
 )

 this.events.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data) //array with all event keys
      const o1 = Observable.from(data)
      this.o2 = o1.flatMap(x => {
          return this.getEvent(x);
      })
 })

 getEvent(eventid: string) {
     return this.db.object(`/events/${eventid}`).valueChanges()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is about what you would want to do:

```
//get all event ids for a particular user
this.eventsRef = db.list(`eventsGuestsLookup/${this.id}`)
this.events = this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes =>
    changes.map(c => (c.payload.key))
  )
)

this.events
.pipe(
  switchMap(eventKeys => {
    eventObservables = eventKeys.map(eventKey => this.getEvent(eventKey));
    return combineLatest(eventObservables);
  })
)
.subscribe(data => {
  // Do whatever you want to do
});

getEvent(eventid: string) {
  return this.db.object(`/events/${eventid}`).valueChanges();
}
```

1. Using switchMap to jump to another observable
2. Using eventKeys.map to loop through all the event keys and query the value changes for each of them.
3. Use combineLatest() to group all the event observables into a single observable.

A simplified version of it all could be:

```
//get all event ids for a particular user
db.list(`eventsGuestsLookup/${this.id}`).snapshotChanges()
.pipe(
  switchMap(changes => {
    eventObservables = changes.map(c => this.db.object(`/events/${c.payload.key}`).valueChanges());
    return combineLatest(eventObservables);
  })
);
```